# Comparación de Collection Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Hola tengo 2 collections en mi controlador cuales son las siguientes

```
$reserva = Reserva::with('user','cancha.reserva')->where('idsede', $id)->get();
$sede = Sede::with('cancha.reserva', 'horarioTrabajo.detalle')->where('idsede', $id)->first();
```

Ahora bien en la vista compararlas en dos pueda ver si esta reservado o no, y si esta reservado me ponga OCUPADO sino RESERVAR, hasta ahi, más o menos, resulta que intento comprar y si tengo tres reservas me las repite
enseño la vista:

```
@foreach($sede->horarioTrabajo->detalle as $hor)
        <tr style="line-height: 4px" >
            <th style="font-size: 13px" >{{date("H:i", strtotime(($hor->start_date)))}}
                - {{date("H:i", strtotime(($hor->end_date)))}}</th>
            @foreach($sede->cancha as $can)
                <td style="font-size: 13px">
                    <input type="hidden" name="reservas" value="{{$fechaActual->toDateString()}}_{{$hor->start_date}}_{{$hor->end_date}}">
                    @foreach($reserva as $res)
                        @if ($fechaActual->toDateString() == date("Y-m-d", strtotime($res->start_date)) and
                        $res->idcancha == $can->idcancha and
                        date("H:i", strtotime(($hor->start_date))) == date("H:i", strtotime(($res->start_date))) and
                        date("H:i", strtotime(($hor->end_date))) == date("H:i", strtotime(($res->end_date))))
                            OCUPADO
                        @else
                            RESERVAR
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Se me ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: Debería mostrar ocupado o reservar]

> Debería mostrar ocupado o reservar, alguna sugerencia o ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

Hola deberías de usar datos tipo DateTime o Carbon... para que tu comparación sea mejor procesada,

```
$fechaActual = Carbon::now()->time(9,0,0);

$res = Model::find(1);
```

```
@if ($fechaActual >= $res->start_date && $fechaActual <= $res->end_date)
```

también podría ser

```
<?php 
$fechaActual = Carbon::now();
?>
```

```
@if ($fechaActual->between($res->start_date, $res->end_date))
```

Comment: Carbon no es un tipo de dato en cambio extiende y amplia a partir de la clase DateTime de PHP